# Store Form Field Data Temporarily

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

ASP.Net MVC 3 using C#

I currently have a form with some dropdown lists populated by a database. If someone wants to add a new item to that dropdown list I need to take them to another form then bring them back. Is there anyway I can do this without rigging it with session variables? Or maybe a way to do it using Ajax to open the 2nd form?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TempData` for this. Although, deep down, `TempData` uses session store but that's abstracted to you via `TempData`.

Going Ajax route is also an option but with so little description, its hard to tell anything in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Model Pop-up for adding item into dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a popup panel to update the value.  Since you're taking the user to a whole new page, I assume there is a lot of logic or prerequisites before they're allowed to add a new value.

You can easily move the logic into a control and throw that control into a panel for the page.  The bonus is that you can also throw it on the existing page, just in case that page is used as part of another function flow.